Contour integration and how direction effects their bounds
I have started complex analysis and have been introduced to the idea of integrating in a positive direction for a simple closed curve.
I was asked to show that $\int{e^z} dz$ = 0 along the contour from 0 to 1, 1 to 1 + i and 1 + i to 0.
The exercise asked us to find the integral along each line and add them to show that it equalled 0. I got the first 2 correct, however, with the third integral, namely $\int^1_0 e^z dz$ I kept getting $e(cos1 +isin1) -1$ which is obviously wrong. I noticed that when I swapped the bounds, I finally got my answer.
My question is, how do I determine the upper and lower bounds in such a case? I've always known to take the upper bound as the larger value and the lower bound of the integral as the smaller value. Can someone kindly explain why it is we take 0 as the upper and 1 as the lower, using some sort of definition or evidence as to why.

Did you use $\oint=\int_0^1+\int_1^{1+i}+\int_{1+i}^0$?

Initially, no. But I would like to know why the last integral has the bounds swapped since our larger value is 1. Shouldn't the larger value be the upper bound?

No, it's based on starting points. You go from $0$ to $1$, then $1$ to $1+i$, then $1+i$ to $0$. Also, complex numbers aren't ordered anyway.

@J.G.so many times it’s referred to as the upper limit. Is there a batter way to refer to the upper bounds to eliminate confusion?

In $\int_a^bf(x)dx$, $a$ and $b$ are the lower and upper bounds in reference to their location on the symbol $\int_a^b$, and that's it.

Always write your contour explicitly:
$$\gamma_1(t) = t, \quad t\in[0,1]$$
$$\gamma_2(t) = 1+ it, \quad t\in[0,1]$$
$$\gamma_3(t) = -t+i, \quad t\in[-1,0]$$
$$\gamma_4(t) = -ti \quad t\in[-1,0]$$
What is the trick with $\gamma_3$ and $\gamma_4$?
Instead of going from left to right or down to up as in $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ you are going right to left and up to down. If you write instead of $\gamma_3$:
$$ \bar{\gamma_3}(t) = t+i, \quad t\in[0,1]$$
You abruptly go from $\gamma_2(1) = 1+i$ to $\bar{\gamma_3}(0) = i$
But with $\gamma_3$ we have $\gamma_3(-1) = 1+i = \gamma_2(1)$ and your contour follows the flow smoothly.
What you need to understand is the concept of opposite curve:

Let $\gamma$ the contour represented by the equation $$\gamma(t) = x(t)+iy(t), \quad t\in\left[a,b\right]$$ and extending from the point $\alpha=\gamma(a)$ to $\beta=\gamma(b)$. Associated with the contour $\gamma$ is the opposite curve $-\gamma$ consisting of the same set of points with the order reversed so that the new contour extends from the point $\beta$ to the point $\alpha$. The contour $-\gamma$ is described by the equation $$ (-\gamma)(t) = \gamma(-t) = x(-t)+iy(-t), \quad t\in[-b,-a]$$

So, $\gamma_3$ is the opposite curve of $\bar{\gamma_3}$ but they are different paths because the direction is reversed.
Hence, in your case we have:
$$\oint_{\gamma= \gamma_1+...+\gamma_4}f = \oint_{\gamma_1}f+...+\oint_{\gamma_4}f = \int_{0}^{1}\gamma_1(t)\gamma_1'(t)dt+...+\int_{-1}^{0}\gamma_4(t)\gamma_4'(t)dt$$
or what is the same
\begin{eqnarray*}
\oint_{\gamma}f &=& \int_{0}^{1}e^tdt+i\int_0^1e^{1+it}dt-\int_{-1}^{0}e^{-t+i}dt -i \int_{-1}^{0} e^{-it}dt  \\
&=& \int_{0}^{1}e^tdt+i\int_0^1e^{1+it}dt-\int_{0}^{1}e^{t+i}dt -i \int_{0}^{1} e^{it}dt\\
&=& (e-1) + ie(-ie^{i}+i)-e^{i}(e-1)-i(-ie^{i}+i)\\
&=& e-1+e^{i+1}-e-e^{i+1}+e^{i}-e^{i}+1 = 0 
\end{eqnarray*}
